# Isolated scope in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Hello guys I am new in angularjs 1.x.
Curious to know what are the meaning of @, = and & in directive in angularjs in following code:

```
scope: {
                title: "@",
                label1: "&",
                valueFrom: "="
            }
```